# cordova Ionic youtube video download

Tags: cordova, video, download, youtube

i have a problem in downloading video using cordova and     ionic          Framework Video is downloaind but only 56 or 60 kb data is   downloaded(not sure whether its video or not) but its not playing in mobile(unsupported video error).Kindly any one help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">      
  <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        
        <a href="#" onclick="downloadvid();">Download Video</a>
        
        <script>
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            function onDeviceReady() {
                alert("Got deviceready");
            }
        
            function downloadvid() {
                var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
//                var inputUri = encodeURI("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01x3rDcNMpw");
                var inputUri = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01x3rDcNMpw";
                var outputPath = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + "sample.mp4";
               
                alert("Starting download to " + outputPath);
                fileTransfer.download(
                      inputUri,
                      outputPath,
                    function (entry) {
                        alert("Download complete: " + entry.fullPath + ", URL=" + entry.toURL());
                        cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
                            entry.toURL(), 
                            'video/*',
                            {
                                error: function (e) {
                                    alert('fileOpener2 error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
                                },
                                success: function () {
                                    alert('fileOpener2 file opened successfully');
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        alert("download error: source=" + error.source+ ", target=" + error.target + ", error code=" + error.code);
                    });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be broken. Please verify it's correct and reformat for better readbility.